# codeigniter file is not uploading on remote server

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, file-upload

this is a code for swf fiel uploading but the problem is it works fine on localhost but not in the remote server.here is my controller

```
function do_upload()
{
    $pid=$this->input->post('Page_id');
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'swf';
    $config['max_size'] = '1048';
    $config['file_name'] =$pid;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    }
    else{   
        $data=array(
            'id'=>$pid,
            'link'=>base_url()."uploads/",
            'file_name'=>$config['file_name']
        );
        $this->file_upload_model->upload_data($data);
        $this->upload_success();
    }
}
```

i have not done anything except just uploading the path and file name to the database in model. see the demo [here](http://leatherbusinessbangladesh.com/index.php/admin/file_upload/upload_form)

Comment: Is the uploads directory writable on the server ?

Comment: Is the base url correct ?

Comment: yap its writable and the base url is also ok..

Comment: Why do you not use `$this->upload->data();` instead of using a handy `$data` array? Compare those and look for differences.

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: @ShayanHusaini there is no error message just a blank page

Comment: @RahatIslamKhan the reason of blank page is you haven't echo anything when upload doesnt work use print_r($error); to see what error message is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$pid=$this->input->post('Page_id');
$config['file_name']        = $pid;
$config['upload_path']      = './uploads/';
$config['allowed_types']    = 'swf';
$config['max_size']         = '1048';
$config['remove_spaces']    = TRUE;

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if ($this->upload->do_upload()) 
{
    //upload successful
    //do something
} 
else 
{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect('controller/method');

    /*
        In the view file you can echo the error like this 
        echo $this->session->flashdata('error');
    */
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work.even it doesn't show any error except a blanl page

Answer (score 0):

You have pass the the field name in the `do_upload` call like this:

```
$config = array(
    'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|swf |png', // pipe seperated file types
    'upload_path' => './uploads/', // should be the root path
    'max_size' => '1048',
    'file_name' => $pid
);

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('your_field_name')) {
    // like $this->upload->do_upload($pid)
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

} else {
    $swf_data = $this->upload->data();

}
```

Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

it may be due to PHP server version and it's option.

1).go to cpanel account

2).click "select php version", in the software section.

3).tap the "fileinfo" chexbox in the php option and save.

now you can upload file perfectly.